# Sorting dates in MySQL table (not sorting BY date)

Tags: php, mysql

How can I sort the dates in a column in a table? (timestamp)

Please note that I'm not asking to sort rows by date, but rather I'm asking how to swap dates in records so that all of the dates are in the correct order; without changing anything else.

So; for example:

```
id     foo      bar
1      A        03-03-2030
2      B        01-01-2010
3      C        02-02-2020
```

becomes...

```
id     foo      bar
1      A        01-01-2010
2      B        02-02-2020
3      C        03-03-2030
```

Preferred solution uses straight MySQL or MySQL and PHP.

Comment: What version of MySQL? And is that date column really a date or is it varchar (it's not a valid MySQL date format...)

Comment: MySQL 8.x and it's a timestamp (as I stated in the question)

Comment: I'd suggest putting the bar column into a new table, sorting it, and putting it back in place. Depending on how many entries you have, you could query the table, sort the results in a PHP array, and then query the table again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your table with a MySQL query using a CTE which computes the `ROW_NUMBER()` for each row, sorted by `id` and `bar`; replacing the `bar` value for each `id` with the one which has the corresponding sorted by `bar` row number:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT id, bar,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn_id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bar) AS rn_bar
  FROM data
)
UPDATE data d
JOIN CTE c1 ON c1.id = d.id
JOIN CTE c2 ON c2.rn_bar = c1.rn_id
SET d.bar = c2.bar
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
id  foo     bar
1   A       2010-01-01
2   B       2020-02-02
3   C       2030-03-03
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bc2819a7f772f6ca3eff1c0c0066abd3)

Comment: Worked perfectly.  And fast!  I hadn't used common table expressions before.  But now I love them.

Comment: I just finished solving it with PHP :)  But this is so much better!

Comment: @HardlyNoticeable yeah, CTEs and window functions are the best things about MySQL8. I'm still stuck on 5.7 on a big project and really missing them...

Comment: @JeffVdovjak sorry about that! If it was MySQL 5.7 or below I think PHP would probably be the easier way to do it.

Comment: @Nick That's okay. Besides the practice of working through a problem, I got to learn something new. I'm very happy with your solution and will explore CTEs soon. A new tool for the toolbox.